# Text Input Responsive Width - Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

### Setting:

I have a `input type="text"`, a `label` and a custom `checkbox` with its own `label` inside a `span` to encapsulate them, inside a `div` on a `li`.

---

### Styling:

- `input type="text"` has aesthetic styling only.
- `label` has `margin-left:5px;`
- `span` has `display: inline-block; float: right;`
- `div` has classes `form-group` and `form-inline` from Bootstrap 3.3

---

### Problem:

The `label` is initially empty but once I type something in the `input`, a script will run, filling in that same `label` with text.

I've been trying to set the `width` of the `input` to be `auto`, having it's width the same as the container it's in, reaching the `span`, so that when the `label` appears, it shortens itself out.

Instead, the `input` remains small. I think I'm doing something wrong but even with some research, I can't understand what it is exactly.

I've tried removing the classes from the `div` (which just breaks it), apply `width=100%;`, which, makes it large, but pushes it and the `label` to the line below.

Could someone provide some help, please?

Here is how it looks below:

[image]
*without text*

[image]
*with text added by `js`*

Link to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/LzqeKq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a wrapper around the input and label using calc to set width 100% - (arbitrary amount to allow for checkbox), e.g.

```
.listWrapper {
  width: calc(100% - 75px);
}
```

You can then set this .listWrapper to display: flex, and give the input flex: 1 1 auto so that the input will grow/shrink as required to take up all available internal space minus whatever space the label requires. You can set flex-wrap to nowrap so it all remains on one line.

Here's an updated codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXwxKz

The relevant updated styles are here, so you don't have to pick through everything:

```
.listWrapper {
  width: calc(100% - 75px);
  float:left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.listWrapper .listInput {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

You may also need to use a clearfix on the wrapper due to the floats. If you have a clearfix style already, apply it to ".form-group.form-inline", if not, add this style to your CSS:

```
.form-group.form-inline:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: That seems to do it for the width (Thank you!) but doesn't compensate for the `label`, pushing it into the next line and that is not the intended. :/

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed the part about the label, I have a fix but it requires a wrapper around the input and label, not sure if that's a deal breaker, but I'll update my answer now.

Comment: It worked to get the intended effect but unfortunately now it's breaking the container it's in, I'm afraid. Possibly because the display styles are different. [Link](https://ibb.co/k0evvm) here.

Comment: I think you need to apply a clearfix to clear the floats, I've added details to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: That fixed it! :) Thank you for the terrific help! Marking as answer

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped :)